# Find My Phone not working

Tags: find-my-phone

I lost my Lumia 810, and replaced it with Lumia 920.

Now, Find My Phone doesn't seem to be working.

The 810 used to automatically update its location, and I could verify this on [WindowsPhone.com](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/my/find).

My 920 never automatically updates itself. If I manually force a location update on the website though, it will locate it.

Also, the settings look buggy. Even though I have the feature turned on, it appears as off. It is also missing some options that were on the 810, notably one to periodically save the location.

Here's what I mean:
[image: Windows Phone Settings / System][image: Windows Phone Settings / System / Find My Phone]

Are all Lumia 920's like this?

Comment: Not an answer, but my Nokia 920 (on EE in UK) has 'ring, lock, erase or find your phone' written underneath 'find my phone' in the settings menu and I have two tick boxes in the settings page - 'Send apps to my phone using push notifications(not SMS)' and 'Save my phone's location periodically and before the battery runs out to make it easier to find'. I would check with your phone operator.

Comment: @Mark Right, I remember those on my Lumia 810. Now I can't remember if there should be that on/off switch or not.

Comment: The screenshots you've got on your answer match my phone exactly, so I guess not, it works well for me.

Comment: Of course, there's irony that you lost your old phone, with the feature turned on :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Haha, I know. But I was silly enough to go out without setting up a PIN lock. Scary stuff...never again.

Comment: Help,find my phone doesnt work for me either. I have a nokia lumia 520 and find my phone is on in settings but Ive lost it and the find my phone on the windows phone website cant find it!!!!!!!!!! help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various tips in [this thread on WPCentral](http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-920/211575-find-my-phone-shows-off-settings-menu-but-appears.html) eventually got me set.

I'm not sure if all of these steps are required or not, but they were for me:

- Turn off **find my phone**
- Force a backup to the cloud in **settings > backup > app list+settings**
- Delete all your phones on windowsphone.com. It will warn you that your phone will no longer be able to connect to your account, ever, unless you factory reset it.
- Factory reset phone. I imported my settings from the cloud and waited.
- Once it was up and running, I turned **find my phone** back on (or checked that box—sorry I forgot!).

My settings look normal now (though I can't remember if the on/off switch should be there):
[image: settings > system][image: settings > system > find my phone]

Comment: i cannot find the second option i.e.., Save my phone's location periodically and before the battery runs out to make it easier to find. can you please help me.....

Comment: I dont have the option to turn find my phone on/off.... I am from Bulgaria is there any reason why I dont have the future ? Using lumia 920 with Black nokia update ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to reset your phone in order to get software to work. It doesn't make sense that I am logging into Microsoft.com/outlook.com with my phone - and it doesn't realize that it is one of my devices.